# How to retrieve domains from CSR (Certificate Signing Request)?

Tags: java, parsing, bouncycastle, csr, certificate-signing-request

I have CSR bytes. I would like to parse it to retrieve all domains from it (including alternative names). How to do it?

I imagine it should be something like:

```
byte[] csrBytes = readMyCSR();
List<String> domains = retrieveDomains(csrBytes);
```

Comment: Domains should be as Common Name, so retrieve CN field.

Comment: @Antoniossss how to retrieve common name and alternative names? I tried with bounycycastle (JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest) but I didn't find the right way to do it.

Comment: Why not google it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914521/how-to-extract-cn-from-x509certificate-in-java OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912390/decode-read-a-csr-certificate-signing-request-using-java-or-bouncycastle

Comment: But `X509Certificate` isn't a CSR. It is an already generated certificate. Another answer doesn't highlight alternative names retrieval.

Comment: If it shows you how te get 1 part of certificate, you should know where to look for any other part of certificate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424266/1527544

Comment: @Antoniossss Thank you very much! It is what I need. Seems that I was searching bad.